# TFS History of a deleted file

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I have ran into a problem with history of a certain file on TFS. I need to find a file history in TFS so I could investigate why was it deleted, but we have hundreds of changesets so manual finding is out of question.
Is there a way to find a certain file history in a specific TFS directory?
I know almost nothing about it - I don't know when it was created, changed and deleted, but I know its directory and full filename.
Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From a Visual Studio commandline:

```
tf history $/Project/Path/To/File.Extension /collection:https://yourserver:port/tfs/collection
```

should give you the information you're after.

Alternatively, turn on displaying of hidden files in the Source Control Explorer settings:

[image]

And then use the View History context menu item directly from the source control explorer.